How can I set the group policy that's available within 'My Groups" using MS Graph?
How can I set the group policy that's available within My Groups using MS Graph?
I want to set the policy to "This group requires owner approval" for a group created using MS Graph. Currently, I can't find a way to achieve this objective looking into the documentation.


Could you include more details on your current requirement? What group policy you are referring to?

The policy you can set for the group in the My Groups UI

@Shuzheng Any update on the issue?


Note that: It is not possible to set the policy to "This group requires owner approval" for a group using MS Graph. Refer this Blog

You have to set it via Access Panel and login as Admin:
Login to Access Panel as Global Admin -> Groups -> Select the Group you want to set membership -> Edit Details -> Select This group requires owner approval

After the above settings the user will get the user will get the pop-up when request to join group like below:


Any update on the issue?

Thank you. I think your link is invalid. You link to Trend Micro, not Microsoft docs

Yeah there is no official MsDoc for it but it is not possible via MsGraph
